# iCloud: Strategy to merge two versions of a file package (common ancestor)?

Tags: icloud, uidocument, icloud-api, nsfileversion

I have a document based app (Mac & iOS) and am trying to find a good way to automatically resolve version conflicts without bothering the user.

My document is actually a file package with lots of small notes stored as text files. The most likely scenario  of a version conflict is that a user modifies a different note on each device so I should be able to merge them by just picking the most recent one of each.

However, with NSFileVersion I only get the *current (most recent)* and the *conflict* version, but I need to know the modification date of the *common ancestor* in order to know that I can use a note without losing changes.

Example flow:

```
Both clients start with note1.txt: base

   Client 1         Client 2    
--------------  ----------------
                 note1.txt: foo
note1.txt: bar
                 note2.txt: hey
```

Based on the above, the version of client 2 would become the *current*, because note2.txt was the most recent save operation.

In the above case I can't simply merge in the most recent version of note1.txt, because I would lose the change that client 2 made ("foo"). I need to first look at note1.txt of client 2 and tell if that was modified compared to the common ancestor ("base").

It would be a simple & elegant solution, but I think that this is not possible to do with `NSFileVersion` alone unless I'm missing something.

An alternative would be to use some sort of timestamped transaction log, but this would complicate things quite a bit...

Comment: In this scenario you're going to lose changes either way. Both the client 1 and client 2 versions are "most recent" for their respective devices. Even if `NSFileVersion` provided ancestry tree information (which it does not do), this does not lead to a solution that won't lose user changes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the scenario above note1.txt cannot be merged automatically, because it was changed by both. However, how could I tell just from looking at the two versions? That's what I meant with the "common ancestor" version. I'd need to know the last modification date of note1.txt before each client changed it… or keep my own transaction log, which complicates things even more.

Comment: @Mark did you manage to resolve the conflicts on a per-file basis for packages? The only `NSFileVersion` I can obtain is for the package as a whole, but I can't obtain `NSFileVersion` or simply a file contents for the individual files inside the package.